# creating a UIImage from a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

Is there a way to create an `UIImage` out of a `UITableView`?

I know about this piece of code that will draw a `UIImage` out of a given `UIView`:

```
-(UIImage*) makeImageOutOfView:(UIView*)view {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);

    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return viewImage;
}
```

but it would only create an image with the size of the table's frame. I would like to create an image that will display the whole table's content. Another problem is that not only that the created image was limited to the table's frame, but when creating the image after scrolling the table had very weird outcomes (only the visible cells out of the first 6 where shown in the image and that's all, the other visible cells were not drawn..)

EDIT - i want to create an image that was drawn out of the content of a tableView, not setting the tableView's background to display an image..

Comment: `self.tblView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NameOfimage"]];`

Comment: i think you misunderstood me, or i didn't explain my self good enough, will edit the question to make it clear

Comment: hey @DavidBenAri have to tryed my answer ... let me know its helps you or not ..?

Comment: @NitinGohel, I accepted your answer and commented there as well.. thx

Comment: @NitinGohel, This approach doesn't work for me. I've changed the frame size of tableView to full content size. But while creating UIImage, only image size get increased but remaining table view cell's are not loaded. The cells already loaded in view only displayed and displays blank space on remaining area in the Image. could you help to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i just Create a DEMO for you and hope its helps you you can capture table image like this way:-

```
-(IBAction)savebutn:(id)sender
{
    [tbl reloadData];

    CGRect frame = tbl.frame;
    frame.size.height = tbl.contentSize.height;
    tbl.frame = frame;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tbl.bounds.size);
    [tbl.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *saveImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage);
    NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",1];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [fileMan createFileAtPath:pdfFileName contents:imageData attributes:nil];



}
```

This is a Screen Shot of capture image:-

[image]

capture image contain full of table cell top to bottom please download the demo of it:-

http://www.sendspace.com/file/w48sod

Comment: resizing the tableView frame's height to be the contentSize's height, made the trick.. (changing the tableView frame's height to be the contents height, will populate all cells at once, allowing to create an image with the full content of the table)

Comment: @NitinGohel, This approach doesn't work for me. I've changed the frame size of tableView to full content size. But while creating UIImage, only image size get increased but remaining table view cell's are not loaded. The cells already loaded in view only displayed and displays blank space on remaining area in the Image. could you help to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is, create an `UIView`, add all cells one below another you want in the image and finally convert that `UIView` into an image using the code you have.

I think that should work.

Comment: I also thought about it, this would be my last resort, but i wanted to ask first, maybe there is a more elegant way..

Comment: I doubt there would be another way, because table cells are generated dynamically and reused, it is not possible to have all cell contents at one go by any other way.

Comment: it can possible just download my created demo and add more cell by array and click save button you get all full Table as a image :)

Comment: Why the down vote? The person who has done it pls specify reason for the same.

Comment: i dont see a down vote, anyway, @NitinGohel answer was nice. changing the tableView frame's height to be the contents height, will populate all cells at once, allowing to create an image with the full content of the table..

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
UIImage* image = nil;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(tableView.contentSize, NO, 0.0);

CGPoint savedContentOffset = tableView.contentOffset;
CGRect savedFrame = tableView.frame;

tableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.contentSize.width, tableView.contentSize.height);

[tableView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

tableView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
tableView.frame = savedFrame;

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
}
```

[image]